# SQL Server: Is there a performance cost to computed columns?

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, query-performance

If I include a computed column in a table, does it place a perfomance burden on it?

For example, if I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    givenname …,
    familyname …,
    fullname AS givenname+' '+familyname
);
```

… does it recalculate every time I `SELECT` from the query?

Would it help if the computed column is `PERSISTED`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> does it recalculate every time I SELECT from the query

**If** that column is references in a query then the calculation will be performed at least once during the query. This is (yet another) good reason to avoid `select * ...` - if you have a query against the `users` table that doesn't reference the `fullname` column then no calculation will be performed.

> Would it help if the computed column is PERSISTED

Obviously, the calculation doesn't need to be performed, but you're now paying for a small amount of storage and I/O costs in having the *retrieve* the persisted data.

But in short, don't try to second guess these things. If this is a common calculation, create a computed column for it. Later, once you have *performance goals* and can *measure* your performance, you can assess whether it has a *meaningful* performance issue and whether the `persisted` trade off (calculation vs storage) has any effect on this.

Comment: Adding to this, maybe it's better to also check computing that column server-side after you retrieve data from database. Calculating in c#/php/etc is way better than calculating in sql and you save some storage for the cost of memory.

Comment: As regards storage, I generally argue that in 2018, if you are worried about storage, get a bigger box. Storage is generally cheaper than performance. In this example. presuming the the results don’t need re-calcuating, I should imagine that if you only want the `fullname`, then a persisted column would be cheaper both in processing and I/O. Sorry it’s taken me so long to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the computed column is PERSISTED, there is no performance issue in selecting the data (but there is in inserting them).

And yes, it is calculated every time you select the data.

Answer (score 2):

My tests indicate ,even if you persist the column,the are calculated every time when you select ..

below is some test data

```
create table numm
(
id int,
 col_not_persist  as id+1,
col_persist as id+1 persisted
)

insert into numm
(id)
select number from Numbers--just numbers from 1 -1000000
```

now when you query

```
select * from numm
```

execution plan shows two scalar operator(costed less though) and if you can see the definition on top right hand corner.. you can see they are calculated every time they are referenced

[image]

Comment: Your test is not valid because you created both types of columns on the same table. Create ONLY a PERSISTED column and you will see that there's only one compute scalar.